# Express.js showing ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, express

I have installed node(v4.1.2) and express(4.13.3)

Node Server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

After running the node file and upon calling http://localhost:3000/ gives me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Comment: Try for some other port..

Comment: i just checked. It was running as ipv6 address. Is this an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you run in powershell at server directory?

```
node app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You are listening on port 3000.

So Try http://localhost:3000

Comment: Code is fine & working. Are you getting any error message ( Port in use ? )

Answer (score -1):

At first install Node.js body parsing middleware.

Installation: `npm install body-parser`

Then add the following lines:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

I think your problem will be solved. For more details, visit -
http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: Not related to the issue at all.